# Validate HTML Textbox in MVC 5 without Model and Entity Framework

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I just want to Validate my `HTML` text box required field validator in `MVC 5`,
 My View,its very important to use the `onclick` event,please guide,I have already wasted 3 hours on this I know its very simply, I tried [this link](http://www.dotnetspan.com/2014/11/validate-fields-not-in-model-entity-in-aspnet-MVC5.html) but it didn't worked

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Controller"))
       {
       <input id="txtsearch" type="text" name="searchbox" />
       <input id="Button1"  type="submit" value="Search" 
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Search","Video")'" />
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the required/title attributes (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Search","Video")" method="POST">
  <input id="txtsearch" type="text" name="searchbox" required title="Your validation message here." />
  <input id="Button1"  type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Custom HTML5 Form Validation:
http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2012/11/21/html5-form-validation/

Browsers compatibility
http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: Hi, your solutions works fine but now as I am using form Action my hit is not going to the Action Method,I think it has connection with RouteConfig  my config is                                                                                                                                                                                            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "videosearch",
            url: "video/search",
            defaults: new { controller = "video", action = "search" }
            );

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, you also need to add
method = "POST" in the form. Edited my answer.

Comment: So Sorry, I thaught that by giving a positive comments count but where is the option to mark this as solution.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to to Vote up but the intellisense says Vote up requries 15 reputation and I don't have it,I seriously want to accept you answer as it helped me a lot.